# MVVM - Display messages from multiple model entities in the view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logging, mvvm

Good afternoon,

In my project I have a view that contains a listview object. Now I have a class (model) called ControlUnit that needs to report its progress to the view. Most of the time, there will be multiple ControlUnit objects at a given time.

For example, in my view model, I will call a ControlUnit.DoWork() for every ControlUnit objects I have in my list, and when that work is done, I want every unit to add to the listview a message that looks like this : "01/04/2015 16:00:00 - ControlUnit1 finished work."

I'm new to MVVM and am actually revamping an old winforms application I did a while back to MVVM as a way of practicing. In WinForms I just raised an event that had a "message" property and handled that in the code of the form itself.

```
public class ControlUnit()
{
public string IpAddress {get;set;}
public string RootPassword {get;set;}

public void DoWork()
{
//Run some telnet commands
//Report result to View (in listview)
//Let's say I run a "uptime" command, I want to return the result of that command and display it in the listview in my view.
}
}

public class DataCollectorViewModel()
{
private List<ControlUnit> _unitList;

public void StartLogging()
{
_unitList.Add(new ControlUnit(IpAddress1,RootPassword1);
_unitList.Add(new ControlUnit(IpAddress2,RootPassword2);
_unitList.Add(new ControlUnit(IpAddress3,RootPassword3);

foreach (ControlUnit cu in _unitList)
{
cu.DoWork();
}

}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without a code example, it's hard to understand your scenario. If your view-model calls the model `DoWork()` method, then the view-model is doing controller duties, so it seems reasonable the view-model will subscribe to a model's `WorkCompleted` event and update the `ListView`. You could either append the items directly, or more idiomatically (I think) maintain a list of messages bound to the `ListView`, and append the items there. Have you tried anything at all yet? Maybe you should, which will help you present a more specific question.

Comment: I actually noticed a mistake in my explanation before reading your response. DoWork() is part of ControlUnit. Editing my post now.

Comment: have you looked at ObservableCollection?  Sounds like it might be a good fit.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [DataTemplates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object that will hold the list of messages and then pass that same object to every viewmodel you want showing messages. Then in your UI you should bind to that List of messages something like this:

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void SendMessage(string msg);
}

public class MessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Messages.Add(msg)));
    }
}

public class ViewModel1 
{
    private readonly IMessageHandler _messageHandler;

    public ViewModel1(IMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }
}

public class ViewModel2 
{
    private readonly IMessageHandler _messageHandler;

    public ViewModel2(IMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }
}
```

Your main application viewmodel needs to instantiate the MessageHandler class and pass it around so every one has the same instance. In your view you should bind to the Messages collection. To make it even more elegant you can also use an IOC container.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm trying to accomplish. This should put me on the right path. Thank you and everyone who took the time to read this.